# Find rolling line of best fit in SQL

Tags: sql, linear-regression, modeling

I'm trying to find the rolling line of best fit for a set of data, when we look at groups of five points at a time, ordered by the x value. In other words:

- For rows 1-4 there is no value, because we don't have 5 total values yet
- For row 5, get the slope and yIntercept for rows 1-5
- For row 6, get the slope and yIntercept for rows 2-6
- For row 7, get the slope and yIntercept for rows 3-7
- For row 8, get the slope and yIntercept for rows 4-8
- For row 9, get the slope and yIntercept for rows 5-9

Here's the values I'm aiming for, in an Excel sheet and plot. The values for `slope` and `yIntercept` are correct according to pen-and-paper and online linear regression calculation:

[image: Excel screenshot]

...and here's the SQL I have so far:

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT 1 AS x, 9 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS x, 7 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS x, 5 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS x, 3 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS x, 1 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS x, 1 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS x, 1 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS x, 1 AS y UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS x, 1 AS y
),
rollingAverages AS (
    SELECT
        dataset.*,
        AVG(dataset.x * 1.00) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [xMean],
        AVG(dataset.y * 1.00) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [yMean],
        SUM(1) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [yCount]
    FROM dataset
),
mValue AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN yCount < 5 THEN NULL ELSE x - yCount + 1 END AS xStart,
        CASE WHEN yCount < 5 THEN NULL ELSE x END AS xEnd,
        CASE
            WHEN yCount < 5 THEN NULL
            WHEN SUM((x - xMean) * (x - xMean)) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE
            SUM((x - xMean) * (y - yMean)) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            / SUM((x - xMean) * (x - xMean)) OVER (ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        END AS slope
    FROM rollingAverages
),
-- This is the y intercept at the start of the range, i.e. 40 trading days before "today"
yIntercept AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        yMean - slope * xMean AS yIntercept
    FROM mValue
),
channelNowMidpoint AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM yIntercept
)

SELECT *
FROM channelNowMidpoint
ORDER BY x
```

I'm not getting the correct values for `slope` or `yIntercept`, I think because the line-of-best-fit algorithm I'm using expects an unbounded set of values, so the calculations I get for `xMean` and `yMean` have lost context by the time I get to the CTE named `mValue`. For reference, you can find a line-of-best-fit algorithm that uses the "least squares" method [here](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit).

See below for the values I'm getting when I run this SQL in SSMS:

[image: SSMS output]

As you can see, where `x = 5`, the `slope` or `yIntercept` are correct, but after that it is incorrect. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and how to get the values I'm aiming for.

Comment: Calculation of `slope` is not correct in your Excel. (You did not take the sum of the last 5 rows of `(x-xMean)*(y-yMean)` and also not for `(x-xMean)*(x-xMean)` ).   I rebuild the calculation and have same result as your SSMS, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=701161df0cd38001250b71b4ef51a55b)

Comment: Getting the same results as me just means you're reproducing the issue. Take for example the last line, which should be a line-of-best-fit for `[(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1)]`. The equation that fits those points is `y = 1` or `y = 0x + 1` making `slope = 0, yIntercept = 1`. The values we are both getting are `slope = -0.8, yIntercept = 6.6` which is wrong.

Comment: The value in your Excel, which show `0` does not mean it's correct.  Currently you take the mean of the last 5 rows, when turning that down to 3 the slope approaches 0 much sooner, or you need to add extra values (until x<13) until the slope approaches `0`.

Comment: see my Excel sheet (external link: https://mega.nz/file/tvZQBDII#JsUbrx19RuKuWPmxm7FieoddCsljWwSVNHX7s9yE_Ko )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. The problem with using window functions in this case is we're getting the values of `xMean` and `yMean` at the row being processed, not at the lead row of the window.

In order to fix this, the `mValue` CTE needs to join back to the `dataset` CTE to get the values for `x` and `y` then stop using window functions, so that the `xMean` and `yMean` values are static for each row:

```
mValue AS (
    SELECT
        ra.*,
        CASE WHEN ra.yCount < 5 THEN NULL ELSE ra.x - ra.yCount + 1 END AS xStart,
        CASE WHEN ra.yCount < 5 THEN NULL ELSE ra.x END AS xEnd,
        CASE
            WHEN ra.yCount < 5 THEN NULL
            WHEN SUM((ds.x - xMean) * (ds.x - xMean)) = 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE
            SUM((ds.x - xMean) * (ds.y - yMean)) / SUM((ds.x - xMean) * (ds.x - xMean))
        END AS slope
    FROM rollingAverages AS ra
    INNER JOIN dataset AS ds
        ON ra.x - ds.x BETWEEN 0 AND 4
    GROUP BY
        ra.x,
        ra.y,
        ra.xMean,
        ra.yMean,
        ra.yCount
),
```

Results:

[image]